# MATLAB: how to locate the nth appeared number in a loop?

Tags: matlab

For example,

```
for i = 1:10

x = i + 2

s(1:i) = (x > 4);

result s = [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]'
```

how to located the column and row of the first "1" appeared in s?

Look for a script.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a vector like `s` it's easy

```
find(s==1,1)
```

should do what you want.

Comment: As a note, the solution here is equivalent to `find(s==1,1,'first')`. To find the final appearance, you can similarly use `find(s==1,1,'last')`. To get column and row indices, use `[r c]=find(...)`.